# Fetch numeric values only

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get the numeric values. I have a query using regexp_substr twice; I want to merge it into one.

Table has values like this:

```
Column A
---------
123ABC
3ABC
23ABC
0000000ABC
123ABC8484848484
```

SQL query:

```
select 
    a, REGEXP_SUBSTR(a, '[0-9]+') || REGEXP_SUBSTR(a, '[0-9]+$') as numeric_values 
from a;
```

Comment: `3ABC` is a value; its substrings `3` and `ABC` are .. substrings .. they are not "values". However, from your query attempt, it seems you don't actually need to get numeric "values" - you are trying to return the digits from the input strings. Is that correct? Then: can the digits appear anywhere in the strings? And if so, do you need to return ALL the digits? For example, what is the expected output from input `'AB123CD44EFG980X'`? If it's ALL the digits (`'12344980'`) then your query attempt is wrong - it will not produce this result.

Comment: OR do you know beforehand that there are at most two groups of digits, and if there are two, the second one will always be at the end of the string?

Answer (score 4):

You could phrase this using a regex replacement to remove non numeric characters:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(a, '[^0-9]', '') AS numeric_values
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: @tim...Thank you, however, if still want the result using only one regexp_substr then is it possible?

Comment: @JaspreetSingh AFAIK `REGEXP_SUBSTR` can only return a single substring, so your current approach might the best you can do if you use that method.

Comment: the third argument is redundant